# Inserting CSV File into MYSQL DB via Windows Powershell

Tags: mysql, powershell

I'm trying to fill my db with a csv file via windows powershell and I'm getting following error:

Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "ExecuteNonQuery" mit 0 Argument(en):  "ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-8.0.29]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{Filiale=0; Jahr=2010; Auftrag_Monat=9; Auftrag_Woche=38; LE_Jahr=0; LE_Monat=0;' at line 1"
In C:\PowerSSkripte\CSV Insert.ps1:28 Zeichen:5
+$stmt.ExecuteNonQuery()

**This is my code:**

```
$Conn = new-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
$Conn.ConnectionString = "DB-Connection"
$Conn.Open()

$query = "DELETE  FROM akustik"
$stmt = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($query,$Conn)
$stmt.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The delete is working as intended!

**Now I'm trying to insert the csv into my db:**

```
$data = Import-Csv C:\TextExport\Akustik.csv
$query = "INSERT INTO akustik (Filiale, Jahr, Auftrag_Monat, Auftrag_Woche, LE_Jahr, LE_Monat, LE_Woche, Anzahl, Anzahl0, Umsatz) VALUES ($row.Filiale, $row.Jahr, $row.Auftrag_Monat, $row.Auftrag_Woche, $row.LE_Jahr, $row.LE_Monat, $row.LE_Woche, $row.Anzahl, $row.Anzahl0, $row.Umsatz)"
$stmt = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($query,$Conn)

foreach($row in $data[0]){ #for testing i want only to insert the first row of my csv so im using data[0]
    $stmt.ExecuteNonQuery()

}
```

I'm getting following error.
error:
Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "ExecuteNonQuery" mit 0 Argument(en):

"ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-8.0.29]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{Filiale=0; Jahr=2010; Auftrag_Monat=9; Auftrag_Woche=38; LE_Jahr=0; LE_Monat=0;' at line 1"
In C:\PowerSSkripte\CSV Insert.ps1:28 Zeichen:5

- ```
  $stmt.ExecuteNonQuery()
  ```

row 28 is: **$stmt.ExecuteNonQuery()** the syntax should be fine cause its the same when I'm inserting sth. into my db via MYSQL Workbench.

When I'm changing my insert statement to:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO akustik (Filiale, Jahr, Auftrag_Monat, Auftrag_Woche, LE_Jahr, LE_Monat, LE_Woche, Anzahl, Anzahl0, Umsatz) VALUES (99, 3002, 12, 12, 3002, 12, 12, 12, 12, 250000.000)"
```

everything is working fine....

I hope somebody can help me to fix this little issue.

Thanks in advance.

Greetings littleStudent

Comment: You are trying to use a PowerShell string as a kind of template, hoping it will automatically resolve the properties of `$row` within the loop. Doesn't work like that. PowerShell string interpolation happens only one time, when the string literal is _defined_. Have a look at MySQL _parameterized queries_ instead.

Comment: Also, it would be a lot easier to use load data statement to load the contents of a csv file

Comment: Thank you very much for yout input zett42 and Shadow. i will try it out as soon as i'm home

Comment: I tried to insert the csv with a cmdlet but i have problems with the db connection. is Write-SqlTableData only for Mycrosoft SQL Server? there is no option to insert user and password so i cant connect with the db...

Comment: Now I have only one problem but I think i will fix it soon. I'm trying to insert decimal values with a decimal limiter , instead of . thats cause the csv has the "," as decimal limiter so I need to find how to ignore this

Comment: This is the error:
Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "Fill" mit 1 Argument(en):  "Incorrect decimal value: '0,000' for column 'Umsatz' at row 1"
In C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\simplysql\1.9.0\Providers\MySql\provider.ps1:42 Zeichen:13
+             $da.Fill($ds)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MySqlException